# Magento 2 : Service worker not loading in PWA

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, pwa

I have added the below script to my header to load service worker on load .When I load my website and check applications tab from inspect on browesr it shows nothing .

```
<?php $ajaxUrl = $block->getUrl('pwa/index/subscribeTopic'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"], function ($) {
        // Register Service Worker
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                var baseUrl = '<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() ?>';
                navigator.serviceWorker.register(baseUrl + 'serviceWorker.js').then(function (registration) {
                    // Registration was successful
                    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
                }, function (err) {
                    // registration failed :(
                    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
                });
            });
        }

        function subscriberTopic() {
            messaging.getToken()
                .then(function (currentToken) {
                    if (currentToken) {
                        var subUrl = 'https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/' + currentToken;
                        // subscriber topic
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<?php echo $ajaxUrl ?>',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {subUrl: subUrl},
                            success: function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                console.log("Cannot get data");
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                });
        }

        navigator.serviceWorker && navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (serviceWorkerRegistration) {

            window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
                // beforeinstallprompt Event fired

                // e.userChoice will return a Promise.
                // For more details read: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises
                e.userChoice.then(function (choiceResult) {

                    console.log(choiceResult.outcome);

                    if (choiceResult.outcome === 'dismissed') {
                        console.log('User cancelled home screen install');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('User added to home screen');
                    }
                });
            });

            messaging.useServiceWorker(serviceWorkerRegistration);
            messaging.requestPermission()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
                    subscriberTopic();
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
                });

            messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
                console.log("Message received. ");
                if (payload.notification) {
                    var notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
                    var notificationOptions = {
                        body: payload.notification.body,
                        icon: payload.notification.icon,
                        badge: payload.notification.icon
                    };
                    serviceWorkerRegistration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
                        notificationOptions);
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

This is me serviceworker.js

```
/**  * @copyright Copyright (c) 2017 www.tigren.com  */ importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-app.js'); importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': '243456161043' });

const messaging = firebase.messaging(); var CACHE_NAME = 'pwa-tigren-cache-v1'; var SWversion = '81';

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    // Perform install steps
    event.waitUntil(
        self.skipWaiting()
    ); });

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function (cacheNames) {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(function (cacheName) {
                    return caches.delete(cacheName);

                })
            );
        })
    );
    return self.clients.claim() });

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    if (event.request.method !== 'POST' && event.request.url.toString() &&
        event.request.url.toString().indexOf('/admin/') === -1 &&
        event.request.url.toString().indexOf('/checkout/') === -1 &&
        event.request.url.toString().indexOf('/cart/') === -1 &&
        event.request.url.toString().indexOf('/key/') === -1 &&
        event.request.url.toString().indexOf('/adminhtml/') === -1 &&
        event.request.url.toString().indexOf('/serviceWorker/') === -1) {
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request)
                .then(function (response) {
                    // Cache hit - return response
                    if (response) {
                        return response;
                    }

                    // IMPORTANT: Clone the request. A request is a stream and
                    // can only be consumed once. Since we are consuming this
                    // once by cache and once by the browser for fetch, we need
                    // to clone the response.
                    var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

                    return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
                        function (response) {
                            // Check if we received a valid response
                            if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                                return response;
                            }

                            // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
                            // and because we want the browser to consume the response
                            // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
                            // to clone it so we have two streams.

                            var responseToCache = response.clone();
                            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                                .then(function (cache) {
                                    cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);

                                });

                            return response;
                        }
                    );
                })
        );
    } });

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log('[serviceWorker.js] Received background message ', payload); });

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    event.notification.close(); });
```

My site does not have ssl certificate . Is that could be the issue ?
Please Help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PWAs/Service workers do require an SSL certificate/HTTPS.

> **You need HTTPS**
>
> During development you'll be able to use service worker
> through localhost, but to deploy it on a site you'll need to have
> HTTPS setup on your server.
>
> Using service worker you can hijack connections, fabricate, and filter
> responses. Powerful stuff. While you would use these powers for good,
> a man-in-the-middle might not. To avoid this, you can only register
> service workers on pages served over HTTPS, so we know the service
> worker the browser receives hasn't been tampered with during its
> journey through the network.
>
> GitHub Pages are served over HTTPS, so they're a great place to host
> demos.
>
> If you want to add HTTPS to your server then you'll need to get a TLS
> certificate and set it up for your server. This varies depending on
> your setup, so check your server's documentation and be sure to check
> out Mozilla's SSL config generator for best practices.

[Source - developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https)

Comment: cool that worked . Now I am getting push notifications as well but only to android . Is there any thing I have to do for iOs to recieve push notifications for pwa .

Comment: Safari (iOS and OSx) doesn't support push notifications yet, it's taking Apple a loooong time to add this functionality. https://caniuse.com/#search=push.

For Safari desktop you can send push notifications with Apple's own method https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/, as for iOS I don't think there is a way for PWAs to send push notifications yet :(